# Java scanner with 2 hasNext()

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner, reader

I would like to restore an object from a CSV file. I need to know if scanner has 2 next values: scanner.hasNext()

the problem is my visit constructor takes 2 parameters and I need to ensure 
there are at least 2 left in my csv file.

here is the relevant code:

```
    /**
 * method to restore a pet from a CSV file.  
 * @param fileName  the file to be used as input.  
 * @throws FileNotFoundException if the input file cannot be located
 * @throws IOException if there is a problem with the file
 * @throws DataFormatException if the input string is malformed
 */
public void fromCSV(final String fileName)
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, DataFormatException
{
    FileReader inStream = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inStream);
    String data = in.readLine();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(data);
    scan.useDelimiter(",");
    this.setOwner(scan.next());
    this.setName(scan.next());
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        Visit v = new Visit(scan.next(), scan.next());
        this.remember(v);
    }
    inStream.close();
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: there is no direct way, you need to do it manually!

Comment: Hack one: use the Scanner to read the line only, not the individual tokens on the line, and then use `String#split(...)` to split each line. You'll know how many items are in the array. Best solution one: use a CSV parser -- use the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hasNext() can also take a pattern, which provides quite a nice way to check this:

```
String pattern = ".*,.*";
while (scan.hasNext(pattern)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To address directly what I think you're asking:  You can check `scan.hasNext()` inside the while loop.

```
public void fromCSV(final String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, DataFormatException
{
    FileReader inStream = new FileReader(fileName);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inStream);
    String data = in.readLine();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(data);
    scan.useDelimiter(",");
    this.setOwner(scan.next());
    this.setName(scan.next());
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String first = scan.next();
        if(scan.hasNext()) {
            String second = scan.next();
            Visit v = new Visit(first, second);
            this.remember(v);
        }
    }
    inStream.close();
}
```

Although I think you're asking about the using `scan.hasNext()` in the while loop,  you should also be checking before `this.setOwner(scan.next())` and `this.setName(scan.next())`.

It might be better to take another approach to the problem as suggested by  Hovercraft Full Of Eels in the comments.  Better yet, since this is a CSV file, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by using a library such as [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) or [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: dbank,  thanks for the reply.  In my csv, the first 2 fields are fixed.  These are the owner name and rthe pet name.  I don't need to check for those because I know that they are there.  If not, then I have exceptions to handle that scenario.

Comment: dbank,  thanks for the reply.  In my csv, the first 2 fields are fixed.  These are the owner name and rthe pet name.  I don't need to check for those because I know that they are there.  If not, then I have exceptions to handle that scenario.

Comment: what I need to to check if whatever left in the csv is a product of 2

Comment: the while loop uses a constructor with 2 parameters.

Comment: @user3738926 I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking now.  Can you please elaborate what you mean by "what I need to to check if whatever left in the csv is a product of 2"?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.   I need to know that:

Comment: 1.  the total number of fields in the CSV is divisible by 2

Comment: 2,  that there are at least 2 fields left after 2 calls to scanner.next()

Comment: @user3738926 Can you give a sample CSV file in the question?  Also some more sample code to give more context would be helpful.  (Along these [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)